How to remove the snippet items from clangd in suggestion list of nvim-cmp?
I disable snippet support of clangd with following configuration.
capabilities = {
    textDocument = {
        completion = {
            completionItem = {
                snippetSupport = false,
            }
        }
    }                                                                                                                                                                                           },

But it only partly works. I don't see 'if~' snippet in suggestion list. But I can still see many other snippets, such as 'else~', 'else if~', 'include~' and so on. If I select these items, they won't be expanded and only the snippet name will be input. For example, if I select 'else if~', only 'else if' is input. It looks like the snippet feature is disabled, but I can still see the items. Is it possible to completely disable it?

Found a way to resolve this issue. In nvim-cmp, add 'nvim_lsp' source as following configuration to filter out snippets.
{
    name = 'nvim_lsp',
    group_index = 1,
    entry_filter = function(entry, ctx)
        return require('cmp.types').lsp.CompletionItemKind[entry:get_kind()] ~= 'Snippet'
    end
},     

Still don't know how to remove the snippets directly in clangd.
